# Bubble editing Shiny datatable

Tags: javascript, css, r, datatable, shiny

I am interested in learning how to implement bubble edit on a shiny datatable.

I came across this website, https://editor.datatables.net/examples/bubble-editing/simple that describes how to implement bubble edit but their example is using javascript, html, css etc.. I am not familiar with these languages. I know basic HTML thats about it.

So if anybody can help me incorporate this bubble edit feature which is java, hmtl, css into R for this toy datatable example below that will help me in understand how bubble edit works inside R framework and improve my understanding of datatable. Thanks in advance.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)  # for the diamonds dataset

# ------------------------------------------------#
ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  title = 'Examples of DataTables',
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        'input.dataset === "diamonds"',
        checkboxGroupInput('show_vars', 'Columns in diamonds to show:',
                           names(diamonds), selected = names(diamonds))
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel('diamonds', DT::dataTableOutput('mytable1'))
      )
    )
  )
))

# ------------------------------------------------#
server = function(input, output) {

  # choose columns to display
  diamonds2 = diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(diamonds2[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE])
  })

}

#---------------------------------------------------------#

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I don't think this is easy to do, because editor is a paid function of `datatables` and DT/Shiny does not support the editor function. The best alternative would be `rhandsontable` but I don't know if they have this bubble editing function.

Comment: @warmoverflow, I tried some examples using `rhandsontable` I did not find that visual appealing like datatable. I am thinking there should be a way to incorporate that javascript or css features into those datatables in R, just a thought.

Comment: All that javascript on the link does is to call `editor.bubble( this );` which requires the `editor` plugin, and the `editor` plugin is not free.